# Oscillation when using scipy.signal.decimate with ftype='fir'

Tags: python, matlab, signal-processing

I am porting some code from Matlab (v2019b) to python (3.9.12, scipy 1.7.3). I am seeing differences between the results from the Matlab call `decimate(A, subsample, 'fir')` and `scipy.signal.decimate(A, subsample, ftype='fir')`. I cannot share the code I am working on, but here is a toy example:

Matlab:

```
artest = 1:109;
artestd = decimate(artest, 2, 'fir');
artestd(40:end)
```

ans =

Columns 1 through 12

79.0000   81.0000   83.0000   85.0000   87.0000   89.0000   91.0000   93.0000   95.0000   97.0000   99.0000  101.0000

Columns 13 through 16

103.0000  105.0000  107.0000  109.0000

Python:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal as sg
artest = np.arange(1,110)
artestd = sg.decimate(artest, 2, ftype='fir')
artestd[39:]
```

Out[6]:

```
array([ 79.        ,  81.        ,  83.        ,  85.        ,
        87.        ,  89.        ,  91.15805094,  92.89257099,
        95.39239802,  96.50650778,  99.98896804,  99.62335551,
       105.34812902, 101.32449627, 114.35633594,  81.63376904])
```

I am not super experienced with digital filters, so maybe I am making a simple error. Why does the python output appear to oscillate at the end of the array? Ultimately, how can I get the python to match the Matlab?

I tried to change the order of the filter in Python with the 'n=XX' parameter in sg.decimate. I see that it seems to behave better with odd values, but it still seems to oscillate at the end of the output array.

I am expecting the Python output to accurately match the Matlab output.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but using `iir` filtering instead of `fir` produces linear results.

Comment: When reading the documentation of scipys decimate function, it is stated that the default  order of the FIR is 20 times the decimation factor, however, it is not clear for me which kind of FIR scipy is using. In the case of the matlab function the default order is 30, and the filter is a hamming filter. Additionally the question of how the filters are handling the edges is unclear. Have you considered to use a test tone instead of the rising sequence?

Comment: scipy's decimate decides for you how to deal with signal boundaries. I recommend writing your own decimate function, using any padding method you want. You can even use extrapolation (as Matlab maybe does).

Comment: Please don't add solutions to the question. Instead, write an answer below, then accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up following dankal444's advice. The following worked for me:

```
def FIRdecimate(inputArray, r, nfilt=30):
    if int(r)==1:
        return inputArray.copy()
    b=sg.firwin(nfilt+1, 1/r, window='hamming', pass_zero='lowpass')

    #lead-in points
    inputArrayPadding = 2*inputArray[0] - inputArray[range(nfilt+1, 0, -1)]
    _, zf = sg.lfilter(b, 1, inputArrayPadding, zi=np.zeros(nfilt, dtype=int))
    outputArray, zf = sg.lfilter(b,1,inputArray, zi=zf)

    #lead-out points
    inputArrayPadding=2*inputArray[len(inputArray)-1]-inputArray[range(len(inputArray)-2, len(inputArray)-2*nfilt-4, -1)]
    outputArrayPadding,_ = sg.lfilter(b, 1, inputArrayPadding, zi=zf)
    
    #get start point
    _, gd = sg.group_delay((b,1),8)
       
    #take every rth point
    ndxs = []
    for i in range(int(gd[0]+ 0.75), len(inputArray), r):
        ndxs.append(i)
    
    outputArray = outputArray[ndxs]
    startpoint = r - (len(inputArray)-ndxs[-1])
    outputArray = np.concatenate((outputArray, outputArrayPadding[range(startpoint, startpoint+int(np.ceil(len(inputArray)/r)-len(outputArray))*r-1, r)]))
    return outputArray
```

Comment: I tested this against matlab and it's a perfect match.  Thanks so much!